# How to run VS Code Insider version when I have regular VS Code installed side by side on MacOS?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have both VS Code regular and Insider installed side by side on MacOS. But running `code` on command line always opens up the regular version. How do I open the Insider version instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command for insiders is: `code-insiders`.

[vscode CLI](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line)

Comment: `code-insiders` is not working for me. `command not found`, gonna try to redownload and reinstall and see if that works.

Comment: It works after reinstalling and then running the command `Shell Command: Install 'code-insiders` command inside PATH

Answer (score 4):

You can manually add the current build (whether insiders or not) to your PATH by opening the vscode command pallet and entering Install "" command in PATH.

[image: adding code command to path]